# SQL row to column using nested Case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get a nested case statement to work which in stages is working but now I have nested another case statement it complains about syntax.  I have looked at many examples and can't see where I have gone wrong.

What I wish to achieve is a row per PolicyTransactionId (set in the where clause) with each account code as a column.  This worked for me, where it turns to error is adding the nested entry to look at the debit/credit entry and turning the number to negative where appropriate.

Attempt so far attached.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8db47/3

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PolicyTransactionSplits](
    [PolicyTransactionSplitId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PolicyTransactionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AccountCode] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AccountDesc] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [TransactionType] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Amount] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Adjusted] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0))
  )
;



INSERT INTO PolicyTransactionSplits
    ([PolicyTransactionSplitId], [PolicyTransactionId], [AccountCode], [AccountDesc], [TransactionType], [Amount], [Adjusted])
VALUES
(1551,1096,1000,'Total Transaction Premium','Debit',50,0),
(1552,1096,1010,'Total Net Premium','Debit',50,0)
;
```

...

```
select
  max(case when AccountCode = 1000 then case when TransactionType = 'Debit' then Amount end else case when AccountCode = 1000 then case when TransactionType = 'Credit' then Amount*-1 end) [Total Transaction Premium]
  max(case when AccountCode = 1000 then case when TransactionType = 'Debit' then Amount end else case when AccountCode = 1000 then case when TransactionType = 'Credit' then Amount*-1 end) [Total Transaction Premium]
from PolicyTransactionSplits
where PolicyTransactionId = 10
```

Comment: You're fiddle looks like a deliberate attempt to create unreadable code. Use proper inventing, separate logical statements with parenthesis, then you'll find the problem yourself.

Comment: solved at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8db47/17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to nest `case` statements:

```
select max(case when AccountCode = 1000 and TransactionType = 'Debit'
                then amount
                when AccountCode = 1000 and TransactionType = 'Credit' 
                then Amount * -1
           end) as [Total Transaction Premium],
       max(case when AccountCode = 1000 and TransactionType = 'Debit'
                then Amount 
                when AccountCode = 1000 and TransactionType = 'Credit' 
                then Amount * -1
           end) as [Total Transaction Premium]
from PolicyTransactionSplits
where PolicyTransactionId = 10;
```

It is unclear to me why are you are repeating the same logic.  Perhaps you just want this:

```
select max(case when TransactionType = 'Debit'
                then amount
                when TransactionType = 'Credit' 
                then Amount * -1
           end) as [Total Transaction Premium]
from PolicyTransactionSplits
where PolicyTransactionId = 10 and AccountCode = 1000;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, the top is exactly what I needed (makes complete sense but couldn't get there).  The repeating logic is a copy/paste error.  I have 20+ lines per transaction under different account codes/descs.  I just tried to simplify it to get the answer rather than give my entire procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You get an syntax error because you're missing 2 `end` statements and a comma at the end of the first line, but your logic doesn't make much sense either, because it's this:

```
case when AccountCode = 1000 then 
  case when TransactionType = 'Debit' then Amount end 
else 
  case when AccountCode = 1000 then 
    case when TransactionType = 'Credit' then Amount*-1 end 
  end
end
```

You'll never get to the second part because AccountCode = 1000 is the criteria in both cases. Maybe you're looking for this?

```
case when AccountCode = 1000 then 
  case when TransactionType = 'Debit' then Amount  
       when TransactionType = 'Credit' then Amount*-1 
  end
end
```